# cakephp select field of relationed elements for show in a view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have this  in cakephp, I try choose the field to be displayed in the combobox when creating related data in cake php.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Round'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Round'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('description');
        echo $this->Form->input('text_marked');
        echo $this->Form->input('project_id');
        echo $this->Form->input('User');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

I try select one project with project_title, in the table project, not by 'project_id'. Title are not unique but is more descriptive than id. Can I do this in cake php?

Comment: This is your form and after submit in your controller want to have a query where the search is base to project_title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was easy,Thus we choose the field to display  in the other views that are associated. it was put:

> public $displayField = 'titte'

in the Round model.